# Meetup API integration to post event on Meetup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, meetup

How to implement MeetUp API to create new event from rails application?
How to authorise key to call create meet up API as I am getting  401 error code as I am free member

I have used `meetup_api gem` to call get events API.
How to use that to Post Event ?

I have refer [This](https://github.com/cranieri/meetup_client) and [This](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/event/#create)